# Nonnormal covering space of Klein bottle by Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, klein-bottle

I've been trying to construct a non-normal covering space for a Klein bottle $K$ by some torus $T$.
I've found some non-normal subgroups of  $\pi_{1}(K)= \langle a,b \mid a b a b^{-1}=e \rangle$ that should correspond to Torus covering spaces, e.g: $<a^{3},a^{2}b^{2}>$, but I'm not sure how to describe the covering map $p \colon T \to K$, especially how do I set a partition of the fundamental polygon of $T$ into the squares representing $K$.

Comment: I gave an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/251234/265452).

Comment: Why didn't you accept your own answer?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it.

Let $a$, $b$ span a lattice $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. If we are considering the covering space corresponding to $\langle a^{i}b^{j},a^{k}b^{l} \rangle \le \pi_{1}(K)$, we can choose the parallelogram $P$ made by vectors $ia+jb$ and $ka+lb$, then cut it into squares along the lattice. An edge of $P$ within each square can be mapped homotopically onto the boundary of the square, and the composition of these boundaries should give back $a^{i}b^{j}$ or $a^{k}b^{l}$ that corresponds to the edge.

Take the case $\langle a^{3},a^{2}b^{2} \rangle$ as an example:
[image]

In the parallelogram, the edge $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ are homotopic to $ab$, $a^{-1}b$, so the edge $c_{1}c_{2}$ is presented by $aba^{-1}b=a^{2}b^{2}$.