# Checking normality of a 4-sheeted covering of the Klein bottle by a torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

[image]

The figure gives a 4-sheeted covering map from the torus to the Klein bottle.
I am trying to show that this covering map is not normal, but I got stuck.
(Actually I am solving an exercise to construct a non-normal covering of the Klein bottle by a torus.)
Is there an efficient way to show that this covering is not normal?

Edit: Is this actually a covering map? If we let $a$ denote the loop on the Klein bottle given by the arrow $>>$, then I can't see it's lift starting at the corner point of the torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is not a cover, it is not locally injective near the horizontal edges. You can find a correct construction at [Non-normal covering of a Klein bottle by torus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250710). In the comments there it is also noted that the minimum degree of such a map is $6$.